# form in DNN skin not working

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

i am using dnn6.1 and i have a skin and i created modules in that skin.My problem is i am not getting textbox values with in that skin.

there is a cde in that skin like

```
 <li>
  <form action="http://letmegooglethat4u.com/" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Type then press Enter.." />
  </form>
 </li>
```

when i delete this particular code snippet,its working means textbox values are getting in code behind.my question is is there any problem when we use a form  tag in DNN?

Answer (score 1):

You can not embed a form within DNN Module COntent.

You have to either re-write it to do things differently, such as how I handle certain things per [this blog post](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGMQFjAA&url=http://www.webstrategiesinc.com/blog/how-to-add-a-paypal-form-to-dnn/&ei=RszxT-TuCIH28gTX3PG6DQ&usg=AFQjCNFEiDsosciPaemImlRh4vcLCl2p0w&sig2=DasoboQdEy0Vb_FaxN0amg).

Or iFrame a form.